# Linksys WRT54Gx as Repeater Bridge

Tags: linksys, bridge, router, repeater

I have a Linksys WRT54Gx router with DD-WRT software working fine.

But. Is it possible to use it as a Repeater Bridge when the host router isn't configured to be in the default 192.168.1.1 subnet?

I've set everything from [these instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge). I've also tried setting repeater router's IP address to be inside host's subnet, setting Gateway + DNS IP addresses... But It still didn't work.

Client machines connecting to second router (my Linksys) were configured to use DHCP and also static IPs within host's subnet.

Nothing worked. Can anyone tell me how to configure it to make it work?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I would like to connect to a wireless AP. Since I want my home wifi link to be strong and accessible everywhere in the building I want to use my WRT as repeater bridge.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to connect to a wireless
>   AP. Since I want my home wifi link to
>   be strong and accessible everywhere in
>   the building I want to use my WRT as
>   repeater bridge

wait wait. this in not the mean of bridge.
An example for bridge. Let's say that you have a wired Network A in your building, and wired Network B to your neighbor's building. The mean of bridge is to connect wireless network A with network B.

As i understood, you don't want something like that. So, bridge mode is not what you want (Also in bridge mode usually clients cannot connect to the AP).

Propably you are looking for repeater mode (Meaning that you only want to get your signal stronger)

Have a look at http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Universal_Wireless_Repeater
Also you may be interested to check what WDS and MESH is

Answer (score 0):

"But. Is it possible to use it as a Repeater Bridge when the host router isn't configured to be in the default 192.168.1.1 subnet?"

Should be fine as long as the secondary AP has an IP address within the primary's subnet.

When connected, is the WRT54 able to ping the primary AP?  What was the gateway address for the clients connected to the secondary AP?

Are you able to get it working as a client bridge?  Can you connect to the primary AP with a client station normally?

Comment: No I'm not able to do it in either client or repeater bridge. I set my bridge's IP in host IP address (based on what I got by directly connecting with my computer) and also set Gateway and DNS IPs to host router's IP. Do you mean I should test PING in bridge router/admin screen? Or anywhere else?